# Importing Data into Sqflite

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, local-storage, sqflite

Is there a way of importing data into a `sqflite` local db from a `csv` file.  I would like to then perform an update, by looking at that same `csv` on a remote server and downloading any updates if needed. I have been trying to find info on importing into `sqflite` but to no avail.  I can't enter all 1000 records with approx 8 fields.

Thanks

Comment: You should structure you question better. Make multiple paragraphs with headings. The actual question should be in a paragraph by itself. Skip the initial background. Most importantly, phrase 1 clear question. A question could be "How do I import a csv file into SQLite using Flutter?". If you have multiple questions, make separate posts on SO.

Comment: I have tried to restructure the question.